# How can i use a two dimensional array with a datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have the following array:

```
    string[,] video = new string[4, 2]; // 4 videos, 2 attributes each
    video[0, 0] = "fje89t9d8hd";
    video[0, 1] = "Video 1";
    video[1, 0] = "uruioiose90";
    video[1, 1] = "Video 2";
    video[2, 0] = "5uidf90sd0f";
    video[2, 1] = "Video 3";
    video[3, 0] = "5jlk0fd9k4l";
    video[3, 1] = "Video 4";
```

And I want to populate a datalist like so:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlDesktop" runat="server" BackColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h4><%# (string)Container.DataItem %> </h4>
                <br>
                <iframe width='680' height='380' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

So that when the page loads, all four videos are embedded and each has the corresponding title above it. What would be the proper way to do this? Do I need an ASP repeater? A foreach loop somewhere? I am lost!

Comment: I would strongly suggest moving away from both web forms and arrays. At this point both are largely superseded by MVC and generic collections. Arrays still.have some uses because they are memory efficient vis a vis lists.

Comment: The magic words to answer your question is "binding" and "Datasource".

Comment: but once you bind, how do you tell which part of the array to bind to the right place?

Comment: Don't use an array. Create a class for each video with the various attributes you need.

Comment: What might that look like?